# Replace low-quality audio track in video

Tags: windows-7, video, audio

I'm looking for a program, that can replace low-quality audio track in video with high-quality one from lossless audio file. It also must be available to shift HQ-track position. I want to do these operations at least with MP4-files. I use Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: "Audition is available only as part of a Creative Cloud membership." .... Whelp then 'google' *cool edit pro* <cough>

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/).

From its [list of video editing features](http://www.virtualdub.org/features.html)

> - Reads and writes AVI2 (OpenDML) and multi-segment AVI clips.
> - Integrated MPEG-1 and Motion-JPEG decoders.
> - **Remove and replace audio tracks without touching the video.**
> - Extensive video filter set, including blur, sharpen, emboss,
>     smooth, 3x3 convolution, flip, resize
>     rotate, brightness/contrast, levels,
>     deinterlace, and threshold.
> - Bilinear and bicubic resampling -- no blocky resizes or rotates here.
> - Decompress and recompress both audio and video.
> - Remove segments of a video clip and save the rest, without recompressing.
> - Adjust frame rate, decimate frames, and 3:2 pulldown removal.
> - Preview the results, with live audio.

Answer (score 0):

[FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org) is able to add and replace audio (and video, subtitle, etc) tracks in files without re-encoding.